# How to Access Database on Android Emulator Device

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and using SQLite.

I would like to access the database and run some SQL queries on the emulator handset for debugging purpose. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sqlite3` command. Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#shellcommands

> To use sqlite3, enter a remote shell on the emulator instance, as
>   described above, then invoke the tool using the sqlite3 command.
>   Optionally, when invoking sqlite3 you can specify the full path to the
>   database you want to explore. Emulator/device instances store SQLite3
>   databases in the folder /data/data//databases/.

Example:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.3.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
.... enter commands, then quit...
sqlite> .exit
```

Comment: there's also motodev plug-in which incorporates DB tools into Eclipse